# Map drawing tablet to different screen sizes

Tags: bamboo

Is it possible to map a Wacom Bamboo tablet to different section of the screens based off of the finessess of the task? For example switching between a mapping of the entire drawing tablet to the full screen, to quarter-screen mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Wacom Tablet Properties, the `Mapping` tab lets you change the screen area that the tablet controls, as well as the tablet area for the stylus to use.

[image: Screenshot of Wacom tablet properties]